# Problem in React Routing and react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have my App and Routing like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>

          <div className="container">
            <MyHeader showMenu={this.state.showHeaderMenu} />

            <div className="row">
              <div className='col-lg-3'>
                <MyMenu></MyMenu>
              </div>
              <div className='col-lg-9 page-padder'>

                <Route  path="/" component={SignUp}  exact={true} />
                <Route exact path="/coverletter" component={CoverLetter} />
                <Route exact path="/attachfile" component={AttachFile} />
                <Route exact path="/choosenumber" component={ChooseNumber} />
                <Route exact path="/chooseplan" component={ChoosePlan} />
                <Route exact path="/sendfax" component={SendFax} />
                <Route exact path="/inbox" component={Inbox} />
                <Route exact path="/outbox" component={Outbox} />
                <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />

                <Route exact path="/freefaxsent" component={FreeFaxSent} />

                <Route exact path="/userprofile" component={UserProfile} />
                <Route exact path="/userprofile/updatedetails" component={UpdateDetails} />

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

The last route which is "/userprofile/updatedetails" does not work. I have the LINK inside UserProfile component, and when I click on it, simply nothing happens and there is no error neither. I checked various docs in internet but most of them are outdated.

```
<Link className="ProfileButtons" to="/userprofile/updatedetails">Update Details</Link>
```

Comment: That's interesting. I dont see any reason why it would not work. See sandbox with template: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-mountain-dy4os

Comment: Does the browser url changing after clicking on the link?